# Android: Activity for result pressing back closes the app

Tags: android, kotlin, androidx

In my app, I am opening a Contact activity to pick a contact using the new Activity Result API like this

```
registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.PickContact()) { it ->
            viewModel.setContact(it) 
        }.launch(null)
```

The Contact activity opens, I can retrieve the contact, all this works just fine. But while in the Contact activity, pressing the back button (either the android back button or the back arrow at the top), instead of closing just the contact activity, it exits my app.

I found fixes online for this issue, but only for the old `startActivityForResult` and `onActivityResult` APIs. Is there a way I can change the behavior of the back button when opening an activity for result for the new API as well?

Edit: Noticed the behavior both on emulator and on physical device

Comment: did you tried overriding onBackPressed()

Comment: Should I override this method inside the activity that opens this contact activity?

Comment: @AdrianPascu, interesting bug, but I'm afraid it is somewhere either in your code or it is specific to the device you are using. Are you using an emulator or physical device? Could you update your answer and specify which one are you using? `registerForActivityResult` is eventually calling `startActivityForResult`. It is just a complex wrapper with a bunch of features in it using the same old API.

Comment: [Source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-dev/activity/activity/src/main/java/androidx/activity/ComponentActivity.java) Line 141- implementation of `ActivityResultRegistry`. Line 215 - `startActivityForResult` is called. This registry is used to launch activities. I even placed a breakpoint on this line and was able to capture it.

Comment: @JeneaVranceanu Updated the post. Same behavior both on emulator and on device

Comment: @AdrianPascu, what happens on `viewModel.setContact(it)`? Notice that when you press the back button `it` is equal to `null`. Try to comment it out and test your app again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Adrian kindly provided me with a sample of his project.
This answer is based on the results of debugging the sample project.*

There is one "invisible" issue in the code that is caused as the result of interoperability of Java and Kotlin languages. When we call Java function from Kotlin code we get return type of `T!` - where `T!` means "T or T?".

Java allows returning `null` values as we wish. In order for Kotlin to know that the value is explicitly optional Java programmers must use `@Nullable` annotation. Kotlin will pick it up and return `T?` instead.

Since `registerForActivityResult` is Java function we get in return, for `registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.PickContact())`, result of type `Uri!`.

Again, `Uri!` means "Uri or Uri?" - "value or null".

To handle this value in a Kotlin style we can safely unwrap it by using question mark `?`:

```
activityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.PickContact()) { 
    it?.let { contactUri ->
        viewModel.setContact(contactUri)
    }
}
```

*[More about notation for platform types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#notation-for-platform-types)*

Comment: Great answer, thanks

Comment: @baderkhane Thank you! Glad to know that.